# How to list all the hostname in my network?

Tags: 14.04, networking

My machine(linux) is connected to my dorm network using wifi connection and accessing the internet through proxy server. Now my dorm have both lan connection as well as wifi. So some computers are connected on wifi network and some using wired lan. 
I tried nmap, arp-scan but donot find the results.

I want to know the ip address and hostname of all the computer connected in this local network. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know which parameters you tried but

```
sudo nmap -sS -sU -T5 -A -v 192.168.1.0/24
```

usually does the trick. Remember this will take some time and will be noisy because of the `-T5` flag but its your network, so happy hunting.

You can use other tools like

`xprobe2 192.168.0.1` and `nikto 192.168.0.1`

nikto [on github](https://codeload.github.com/sullo/nikto/zip/master)

xprobe2 [on sourceforge](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xprobe/xprobe2/Xprobe2%200.3/xprobe2-0.3.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fxprobe%2Ffiles%2Fxprobe2%2F&ts=1453024374&use_mirror=ncu)

Compile from source to use in either linux or windows

*Here is a simple example of snmp reconnaissance* [hack-like-pro-exploit-snmp-for-reconnaissance-0150181](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-exploit-snmp-for-reconnaissance-0150181/)

For OS **foot-printing** and if you are interested you can look into **snmp hacking** to gather info from a *client server environment*.

There are tools like `snmpget` and `snmpwalk` which are very easy to use.

There are other ways for *foot-printing* *CEH heavy* stuff which needs studying and hands on practice, but in your scenario I don't think that’s worth the time.